# SecItemCopyMatching doesn't find key stored with SecItemAdd

Tags: swift, security, cocoa

I'm writing an app that uses the App Store Connect API and would like to store the private key contained in the .p8 file downloaded from the website in the keychain.

The following code successfully stores a key in the keychain with `SecItemAdd`, then tries to read it immediately, but without success (the error code of `SecItemCopyMatching` is `errSecItemNotFound` and the console outputs `nil`). Running the code a second time causes `SecItemAdd` to fail with code `errSecDuplicateItem`, and `SecItemCopyMatching` again with code `errSecItemNotFound`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    private let secApplicationTag = "com.example.app".data(using: .utf8)!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        do {
            try storeKey("asdf")
            print(try readKey() as Any)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    private func storeKey(_ key: String) throws {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: key) else {
            fatalError()
        }
        let status = SecItemAdd([kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey, kSecAttrLabel as String: "Asdf", kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: secApplicationTag, kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate, kSecValueData as String: data, kSecAttrSynchronizable as String: true] as [String: Any] as CFDictionary, nil)
        if status != errSecSuccess {
            throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: Int(status))
        }
    }
    
    private func readKey() throws -> String? {
        var item: CFTypeRef?
        let status = SecItemCopyMatching([kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey, kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: secApplicationTag, kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate, kSecReturnData as String: true] as [String: Any] as CFDictionary, &item)
        switch status {
        case errSecSuccess:
            let data = item as! Data
            return (data as Data).base64EncodedString()
        case errSecItemNotFound:
            return nil
        default:
            throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: Int(status))
        }
    }

}
```